# How can I wait for the download file to finish downloading in background, then offically download it

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

Title may sound confuzing, so let me explain.
On certain youtube video downloaders, when you download the video, it shows a progress bar and then its instantlly downloaded. When I try to make a user download a file, for instance (on chrome), it shows CHROMEs download bar.

How can I do this using html/css/js, and if required, my express server (server has ytdl).

I couldn't find anything on how to do this but I KNOW it's possible. So please, am I an idiot, or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you send over a file buffer in the response, and then once you receive that response in the front end, prompt the user to save that buffer as a file?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but you could download the file via ajax, show the progress bar, and on complete store the blob in an [object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and let the user download the file from that object url. That way the source for his dowload is basically the browser cache.